# The custom "Buy Now" button in shopify is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

How to create a custom "Buy Now" button in Shopify so that it goes to the checkout page and not to cart. The problem is that when the user for the first time goes to the site clicks the button, he is redirected to the main page of the site and not to the checkout page. When the button is pressed again, everything works.

https://mistdream.org/products/rainserenity-by-mistdream

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSOmz.jpg)

My code

```
    {% form 'product', product %}
                 <div class="item-bottom">

                        <div class="item-left">
                            <h4>quantity</h4>
                            <div class="item-count">
                                <div class="button-container">
                                    <button type="button" id="decrease">-</button>
                                </div>
                                <input type="text" name="quantity" min="1" value="1" id="quantity" aria-label="Quantity of goods">
                                <div class="button-container">
                                    <button type="button" id="increase">+</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item-price">
                        <h4>price</h4>
                        <p>{{ product.price | money }} <span>129.99$</span></p>
                    </div>
                <select name="id" style="display: none;">
                  <option value="{{ product.variants[0].id }}">
                    {{ product.variants[0].title }}
                  </option>
                </select> 

                <button class="button buynow-btn" title="Buy" onClick="instantBuy()">Buy now</button>
                    
              {% endform %}
```

```
 function instantBuy(){
     var $ = jQuery;

   var formParams = $('form').serialize();
     $.ajax({
      url: "/cart",
      type: "post",
      data: formParams,
      success: function(){ 
       window.location.href = "/checkout";
      },
      error: function(){
      }
     })
 }
```

Comment: Is there any APP or script used, that shows the 404 on the cart and collection, and if I try to type checkout direct it returns to homepage, yes then check this issue